# Split an array into equal parts with a maximum of 6 items per array

Tags: php

I am trying to split an array of items into multiple equal parts with a maximum of 6 items per array

for example:

```
5 items in original array --> result: 1 array with 5 items
12 items in original array --> result: 2 arrays with 6 items
7 items in original array --> result: 2 arrays with 3 and 4 items
13 items in original array --> result: 3 arrays with 5,4,4 items
```

I have absolutely no idea how to get started on this

Comment: Have you worked out how to calculate how many items need to go in each result array?

Comment: Have a look at `array_chunk()`

Comment: To get you started: get the number of array elements and divide by 6, rounding up. This tells you how many arrays you'll need. If you divide the number of array elements by this number, you'll get the number of elements to place in each array; however, this can be a non-whole number, so you'll need to figure out how to handle that case. Start from there and you should have something we can help you with if you get stuck :)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Good suggestion for another use case, but it won't do what the OP is asking. For example, the case of 7 array elements would produce arrays with 6 and 1 elements, not 4 and 3 as is desired.

Comment: Oh, right... didn't read closely enough :(

Comment: I think i'm on to something, will update with an answer when i found it. @B.Fleming, thanks for pushing me in the right direction

Comment: @LarsStegelitz No problem. However, you might be onto something. Look at the comments in the documentation for `array_chunk()`. If the helpfully provided user-defined `array_chunk_vertical()` is used and then modified slightly to change the output, it could very possibly work!

Comment: @vincent No problem. You might also consider the discussion I was just having with Lars if you continue to have trouble. I'm sure you'll get this nailed down with a bit more effort. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for. Not exactly beautiful, but working:

```
<?php
$size = 13;
$step = 6;

$input = array_keys(array_fill(0, $size, null));
$count = ceil($size / $step);
$chunk = floor($size / $count);
$bonus = $size % $count;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $output[] = 
        $i == 0 ? 
        array_slice($input, $i * $chunk, $chunk + $bonus) : 
        array_slice($input, $i * $chunk + $bonus, $chunk);
}

print_r($output);
```

Here `$size` is the size of your array and `$step` is the size of the chunks cut from that array. You can play around with those values.

An example output with the settings above would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 12
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did this with a more dynamic programming way, where in we compute the distribution for smaller subproblems and go from `6` to `1`, to see if current `$j` in the code fits in any of the previous distribution.

```
<?php

$arr = [];

$size = rand(1,150);
$range = range(1,$size);
$dist = [];
$dist[] = [];

for($i=1;$i<=$size;++$i){
    if($i <= 6) $dist[] = [$i];
    else{
        for($j=6;$j>=1;--$j){
            if(abs($j - $dist[$i-$j][0]) <= 1){
                $dist[] = array_merge($dist[$i-$j],[$j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// echo $size,PHP_EOL;
// print_r($dist[$size]); print the distribution if you want.

$result = [];

$curr_index = 0;
foreach($dist[$size] as $chunk_size){
    $result[] = array_slice($range,$curr_index,$chunk_size);
    $curr_index += $chunk_size;
}


echo $size,PHP_EOL;
print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/gCWB2 (Note that the output there is different for each version of PHP as a different random number of an array size is generated each time).

**Update:** You can further optimize the above code for this heavy line **$dist[] = array_merge($dist[$i-$j],[$j]);**, but this I leave as an exercise to you(hint: store only the smallest starting one with it's count).